# firebase cloud storage APIs in official document aren't working correctly

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

At first, I initialized project using npm.

```
npm init
npm install --save firebase
```

Afterwards, I wrote the following code and execute using Node.js stable version(v8.9.4).

```
const firebase = require('firebase');

const config = {
  apiKey: '<API_KEY>',
  authDomain: '<MY_PROJECT>.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://<MY_PROJECT>.firebaseio.com/',
  storageBucket: 'gs://<MY_PROJECT>.appspot.com/'
}

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const storage = firebase.storage();
```

Then the following error will happen:

```
TypeError: firebase.storage is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/sandbox/google/storage_sample/index.js:12:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I referred the official firebase document.(https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference)

If I use "firebase-admin", there is no issue, and also this works like below.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('./AUTH_FILE.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<MYPROJECT>.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: '<MYPROJECT>.appspot.com/'
});

const storage = admin.storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket();

bucket.
  getFiles().then(results => {
    const files = results[0];
    console.log("Files:");
    files.forEach(file => {
      console.log(file.name);
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error("Error:", err);
  });
```

Is the only way to get access to cloud storage in javascript to use "firebase-admin"?
Or are there any mistakes in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running on node.js, the correct library is firebase-admin, as you've discovered.

The web SDK is for running in the browser, which you are not doing.